# include external figures using relative paths in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

How do I include external figures using relative paths?

I start my rmd file with:

````
```{r setup,include=F}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=F,echo=F)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation',
child.path='/Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation')
```
````

and then include:

```
# Heading 1
some text referring to figure 1. ![Figure 1. a map from qgis](data/gis/fig1alt-location_map2.png)
```

my rmd file is in /Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation/reports/real-time so my understanding is it will look for figures out of that directory. But based on [chunk options help](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package_options) I thought I could use child.path to set relative paths in the document but that does not appear to be the case.

"data/gis" is a subfolder in "/Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation"

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if the question is still relevant for anyone, but I just had a similar problem and couldn't get any of the options of setting paths (root.dir, child.path etc.) to work, but for setting relative paths, this worked for me:

```
![Figure 1. a map from qgis](../../data/gis/fig1alt-location_map2.png)
```

The meaning of `../` is the directory one level above the current location, i.e. `../../` means to go from the current level (in this case /Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation/reports/real-time) two directory levels above (in this case /Users/dosc3612/odrive/CUDrive/real-time_interpolation), where in this case you would find the folder "data" with subfolder "gis" containing the figure

Comment: The answer would be a lot better if you could explain where that file is relative to whatever the path is relative to and what ../../ is.